# ASP.NET Core 3.1 - `Development` value for ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT triggers additional services' lifetimes validation during the startup

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, aspnetcore-environment

I've noticed a strange behavior for ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT

- when i set it to `Development`, my application fails (as it should) due to some services' incorrect lifetimes (aka `cannot consume scoped service...`)
- when i set it to `Local` (we use `Local` for local development; we use `Development` for the develop env where our frontend works), the application works just fine, no errors are thrown, scoped services are consumed by singleton services...

Is there a way to preserve the behavior of the `Development` in the `Local` and other environments? The issue is that I was completely unaware that I was pushing invalid code (cross-checking tens of services isn't an easy task - that's why I assumed that it was done by my app locally).

Also - I tried to pin the line where this additional `Development`-specific logic is implemented but with no luck. Maybe there's someone here who knows the place - I'd really like to spend a short while reading the code.

I created a minimal reproducible example:

Program.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using WebApplication1;

var builder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureHostConfiguration(configHost =>
    {
    })
    .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
    {
        webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
    });

builder.Build().Run();
```

Startup.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using WebApplication1.Services;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services
                .AddControllers();

            services
                .AddSingleton<SingletonService>()
                .AddScoped<ScopedService>();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            app
                .UseRouting();

            app.ApplicationServices
                .GetService<SingletonService>()
                .DoSth();
        }
    }
}
```

SingletonService

```
using System;

namespace WebApplication1.Services;

public class SingletonService
{
    private readonly ScopedService _scopedService;

    public SingletonService(ScopedService scopedService)
    {
        _scopedService = scopedService;
    }

    public void DoSth()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(SingletonService)} - {nameof(DoSth)}");
        _scopedService.DoSth();
    }
}
```

ScopedService.cs

```
using System;

namespace WebApplication1.Services;

public class ScopedService
{
    public void DoSth()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(ScopedService)} - {nameof(DoSth)}");
    }
}
```

launchSettings.json

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "WebApplication1": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": false,
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:8080",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: There are validation options that you can pass when building the ServiceProvider, and when working specifically in the "Development" environment, this validation is indeed performed by default. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicecollectioncontainerbuilderextensions.buildserviceprovider?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0#microsoft-extensions-dependencyinjection-servicecollectioncontainerbuilderextensions-buildserviceprovider(microsoft-extensions-dependencyinjection-iservicecollection-microsoft-extensions-dependencyinjection-serviceprovideroptions)

Comment: See source code https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting/HostingHostBuilderExtensions.cs,290

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the default `IHostBuilder` using `Host.CreateDefaultBuilder`, it will set service Scope and Building validation to `true` when the Environment is "Development". The following is relevant bit of code taken from dotnet's source code:

```cs
internal static ServiceProviderOptions CreateDefaultServiceProviderOptions(HostBuilderContext context)
{
    bool isDevelopment = context.HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment();
    return new ServiceProviderOptions
    {
        ValidateScopes = isDevelopment,
        ValidateOnBuild = isDevelopment,
    };
}
```

You can navigate the source code starting with [Host.CreateDefaultBuilder](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/a103efd28d46af39fc22a77458a11d204226e8d4/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting/src/Host.cs#L53) and ending with [HostingHostBuilderExtensions.CreateDefaultServiceProviderOptions](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/a103efd28d46af39fc22a77458a11d204226e8d4/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting/src/HostingHostBuilderExtensions.cs#L285).

Comment: Thanks, I added `.UseDefaultServiceProvider(options =>{options.ValidateScopes = true;options.ValidateOnBuild = true;})` to my host builder and it did make the errors get thrown. I still can't imagine how the app handles incorrectly registered services if this check is not done. I use scoped services during the startup (for seeding etc.) and they work perfectly without the validations. Any idea where I could look for the answer?

Comment: I don't know how it handles incorrectly scoped services, I would have to look into that. But if a service cannot be built because some of its dependencies are not registered, you will get an Exception when trying to inject that service in another service. That's what the `ValidateOnBuild` property helps you with, it will instead throw the Exception when starting the application.